# Piano what is this symbol name and meaning?

Tags: piano, notation

What is this symbol name and meaning (symbol above the red line) - the line travel from Bass clef through Treble clef, then go back to Bass clef?

It seems that this symbol is not listed in [musical symbols in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_symbols).

[image: upward and downward diagonal lines between staves]